# How to analyze mood data over time?

Tags: time-series, ordinal-data

I've collected data for individuals on a team about their daily mood. Each day, individuals rate their mood on a scale that is assigned the following values: 0 (bad), 5 (so-so), 10 (good). Using the data from the individuals, I can come up with an average mood for the team for that day.

I have several months worth of data for around 10 teams, with team size varying from 3 to 12 people.

I would like to be able to do some analysis with this data to answer questions like "Is this team in a better or worse mood than normal?" instead of just being able to report a numeric value.

What sort of statistical models or calculations should I be looking into? Here is what I have implemented so far:

- Use the past N days of data to compute a "baseline" average and standard deviation. (N is ~30-90)
- Use the past M days of data to get capture the "current feelings".  (M is ~3-5)
- Compute the z-score and use different "bands" to categorize (more than 10% worse than the mean => team is not doing well, more than 10% better => team is doing great, inbetween => team is normal)

While doing my own research, I've run into things like "time-series analysis" and (seemingly) advanced techniques like ARIMA. Would these approaches be worthwhile to investigate further? Is my method valid and reasonable? I am looking for some guidance.

My background is in software engineering; my last statistics class was in high school so if it is more complicated than standard deviation, please try to explain it like I'm still in the 11th grade :-)

Comment: For your issue I would go for hypothesis testing with this [method](http://luna.cas.usf.edu/~mbrannic/files/regression/corr1.html#More%20than%20two) .

Comment: check out Timmermans, T., Van Mechelen, I., & Kuppens, P. (2010). The relationship between individual differences in intraindividual variability in core affect and interpersonal behaviour. European Journal of Personality, 24, 623.http://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/_pdf/Timmermans2010TRBID.pdf